# Convert pandas dataframe column of UTC time string to floats

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, utc

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of strings, with datetimes in UTC format, but need to convert them to floats. I'm having trouble doing this. Here is a view of my column:

```
df['time'][0:3]

0    2018-04-18T19:00:00.000000000Z
1    2018-04-18T19:15:00.000000000Z
2    2018-04-18T19:30:00.000000000Z
Name: time, dtype: object
```

I've been trying this, but isn't working for me:

```
import datetime
for i in range(1,len(df)):
        df['time'][i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df['time'][i], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000Z')
```

Here is the error I'm trying to fix:

```
execfile(filename, namespace)

exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

unsup.fit(np.reshape(df,(-1,df.shape[1])))

X = _check_X(X, self.n_components)

X = check_array(X, dtype=[np.float64, np.float32])

array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-06-29T20:45:00.000000000Z'
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format`:

```
df['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000Z')
print (df)
                             time               time1
0  2018-04-18T19:00:00.000000000Z 2018-04-18 19:00:00
1  2018-04-18T19:15:00.000000000Z 2018-04-18 19:15:00
2  2018-04-18T19:30:00.000000000Z 2018-04-18 19:30:00
```

For assign back:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000Z')
print (df)
                 time
0 2018-04-18 19:00:00
1 2018-04-18 19:15:00
2 2018-04-18 19:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about basic pandas stuff. 'pd.to_numeric(df['time'])' was what I was looking for.