# Converting a pandas column of UTC time to seconds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the column `created_at` is an UTC object (I did `df.dtypes` to find the type). I need to convert it to numeric for all the rows.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112320/convert-pandas-dataframe-column-of-utc-time-string-to-floats), I did below code

```
df['created'] = pd.to_numeric(df['created_at'])
```

But getting below error -

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "2015-02-06 22:24:17" at position 0
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will convert a datetime object to the unix epoch:

```
epoch = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01') 
date_in_seconds = round((date - epoch).total_seconds())
```

Where "date" is a datetime object you want to convert

Comment: Based on your reply, I did this `import datetime
epoch = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01')
df['created'] = df.apply(lambda x: round((datetime.datetime(df['created_at']) - epoch).total_seconds()), axis = 1)`. But getting error `TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>", 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: @nad try:

`df['created_at'] = df.apply(lambda x: ((df['created_at'] - epoch).dt.total_seconds()))`

Comment: I tried that before and got ERROR `TypeError: ("descriptor '__sub__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'", 'occurred at index market_id')`. Thats why I added `datetime.datetime` typecasting

Comment: Are you sure the 'created_at' column is a datetime object? I tested it on a df based on your description and it works. If its not try running:
`df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])`